# Riddle with heavy answer

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Ok, you hacked my other riddles pretty quickly, but this one is meant to give you heat.. There you go:

```
I am born from the death of my mother
and I have millions of secrets to hide.
Like me there are plenty of others
but we are all empty inside.

Maybe you know, I'm never in a hurry
due to my origin sublime.
At the same time, I am always hungry,
not for knowledge,
but for time.
```

Good luck this time. And btw, just one single word I skipped in the last sentence can point you immediately to the right answer. :)

Comment: is the horrible grammar intended?

Comment: no, it is not.. you can edit whenever you like

Comment: nice riddle! shame I was too late for the party

Comment: "The Universe"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just a suggestion mostly , although sublime origin might not stand

> Blackhole

Comment: Somehow I don't think this is it

Comment: hungry for time??

Comment: hungry for time COULD be it. Although I'm thinking that it doesn't perfectly fit :/

Comment: Especially the "empty inside" part does not fit a black hole. +1 anyway, because it seems a solution for the other stuff.

Comment: damn, you are clever :)

Comment: Really?? I just thought it might be, ;)

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi How does the "we are all empty inside" part work?

Comment: @Celos it is more of a clue for the word 'hole'.. It does not have to be 100% correct from the physics' point of view, or should it?

Comment: @zlobi.wan.kenobi ah, fair point. The other clues were describing physical properties so it didn't even cross my mind that one could be a play on words instead.

Comment: I'm not that into black holes. Can somebody explain its origin sublime and hunger for time?  And how about this "empty inside"?

Comment: Haha, "heavy answer" indeed!

Comment: Empty inside??  A black hole "contains" (or is the area around) a singularity - which is all but infinitely dense.  Well, you and the asker seem to be on the same page.  :-)

Comment: Hungry for time = Black holes compress things in space. Things from the fabric of spacetime. I assume "empty inside" is because we are not sure what black holes really are. They might be micro-universes or all sorts of things.

Comment: "sublime" works, because the origin is a star :)

Comment: Would it be possible for you to edit this answer to explain how you reached this conclusion given the information in the question? (A lot of explanation can be taken from the comments, if someone has the time to do this.)

Answer (score 6):

Just a guess , not quite sure where time fits in.

> [A Matryoshka Doll?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matryoshka_doll)

Comment: not what I had in mind, but very original :)

Comment: This was a nice one!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this answer fits the title or the part about "heat" or the missing word in the last sentence (if those are even clues), but I'd guess it's

> an hourglass?

Here is my reasoning:

I am born from the death of my mother

> The bottom is "born" and filled as the top is drained, creating the new from the death of the old

and I have millions of secrets to hide.

> Millions of grains of sand in an hourglass

Like me there are plenty of others

> There are many different types of timepieces, also many different hourglasses

but we are all empty inside.

> There is always at least enough space for one half of the glass to be empty, and the "child" we're referring to always starts empty

Maybe you know, I'm never in a hurry

> Ever stare at an hourglass and try to will the grains to fall faster?

due to my origin sublime.

> Hourglasses measure time, a very sublime concept

At the same time, I am always hungry,
not for knowledge,
but for time.

> The grains constantly fall through into the bottom until the top is drained, but no matter how many times you flip the glass over, it will still be hungry for more

Comment: I really like your interpretation. It is not what I meant, but it is always amazing how creative the people here are. :)

Comment: btw, "heat" is not a hint.. "heavy" is related to the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I tried to figure out some of those lines.

*Born by the death of my mother* possibly means that there are never both of them - maybe I can only make use of one or the old one. *The mother* is not useful anymore/broken/...

*We are all empty inside* could mean that I am going to fill it with something and therefore need to get a new one sometimes.

*You know I'm never in a hurry* at first made me think of a technical device always running at the same speed or an object that is standing still all the time.

*Not hungry for knowledge* means the user will not create value to the object itself by using it. It will only consume or I will consume. *Hungry for time* supports this thought. Also it is kind of empty so I came across a hole. So in order to feed it I will have to wait or use it for a long time, maybe frequently.

I thought of a book or a diary which didn't feel right, especially because of "I'm never in a hurry". I went on and thought of more static object growing wealth over time.

> A piggy bank came to my mind. You have to buy a new one as soon as you kill the old one. It keeps secrets because you never know how much money is inside. Well the "millions" are kinda wrong here, I admit :D

That's it for now. I have to go on with my own riddle. Thanks for sharing!